# Cannot start Ambient Light Sensor (Chrome, MacOS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sensors

Have been trying to experiment with ALS but so far cannot get it to work. I have used the following snippet:

```js
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'ambient-light-sensor' }).then(result => {
    if (result.state === 'denied') {
        console.log('Permission to use ambient light sensor is denied.');
        return;
    }

    const als = new AmbientLightSensor({frequency: 10});
    als.addEventListener('activate', () => console.log('Ready to measure EV.'));
    als.addEventListener('error', event => console.log(`Error: ${event.error.name}`));
    als.addEventListener('reading', () => {
        // Defaut ISO value.
        const ISO = 100;
        // Incident-light calibration constant.
        const C = 250;

        let EV = Math.round(Math.log2((als.illuminance * ISO) / C));
        console.log(`Exposure Value (EV) is: ${EV}`);
    });

    als.start();
});
```

The error that I am getting is: `Error: NotReadableError`. No other errors or warning in the console.

Chrome Canary v97, MacOS 10.15.7

Comment: Have you eventually figured this out?